# c# array collater where the output has the same value every other element

Tags: c#, arrays

This is an extension of something I'm really working on.
It is easy enough to do in a loop but I was wondering if I could find a single-code line.

This is the input:

`byte[] x = new byte[] { (byte)'a', (byte)'b', (byte)'c', (byte)'d' };`

Re-write the values anyway that you like but you get the point.  you have to start with an array of bytes and end up with a collated array of bytes.

Here is the desired output:

`byte[] { (byte)'a', (byte)'z', (byte)'b', (byte)'z', (byte)'c', (byte)'z', (byte)'d', (byte)'z'};`

I tried variations of this but started with what I'm showing and knowing this would not work in itself.

`var y = x.Select(c => new byte[] { c, (byte)'z' });`

At the end of the day since these are only bytes is doesn't matter what the values are.
Just that you can correlate some given value, 'z' in this case.
And in as few lines, preferred a one-line, that is reasonably clear and concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very nearly there - you just need to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`, as for each input element you're creating a sequence of output elements... then you want to flatten that "sequence of sequences" into a single sequence. That's precisely what `SelectMany` does.

So:

```
var y = x.SelectMany(c => new[] { c, (byte)'z' }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Can you find a non-lambda way of doing this?

Comment: @user2367083: Sure, you *could* use a query expression - but it would be longer and harder to read. Why would you want to avoid lambda expressions? What's your actual concern?

Comment: I'm not object to lambda.  But I am old C (Richie/Kernighan) hack.  So a 'native' line is often a position I first come from.  lol

Comment: @user2367083: I suggest you try instead to work with the idioms of the language you're actually using. If you want to write code in a C-like style, write C. If you want to write C#, write in a C# style.

Comment: Lol.  And that spoke to the guy who pushes the envelop in his (mean in my) office.  Personally I'm amazed how people refused to adopt Linq.  But I'll only declare myself a hack. And growing nicely at the same time

Comment: @user2367083: Well I really don't know what you want. You asked for a solution "in as few lines, preferred a one-line, that is reasonably clear and concise". That's what I gave you. If you want to achieve similar goals without using any features that aren't in C#, write a `for` loop. It's not hard, it'll be fairly clear - but it certainly won't be a one-liner.

Comment: Don't take me wrong.  Your answer wins big for me.  You've earned big kudos.  I like pushing & finding limits and applying techniques across languages.  For instance next time I find myself in Python, Javascript, or VB I'm probably going to try to find the distinct difference in those too.